# Request management using services

Tags: javascript

I noticed that some developers are using so-called "services" to manage front end requests, for example:

```js
const httpService = {
  get(url) {
    fetch(url).then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('error')
      }

      return response.json()
    })
  }
}

const getPostService = (url) => {  // this is the service
  return httpService.get(url).then((json) => json)
}

getPostService('/post')
.then(r => setData(r))
.catch(e => setError(e));
```

Is there a reason to create multiple services like: `getPostService` or `getUserService`, or `getDataService`, or the implementation is the same if inside the code will do:

```js
httpService.get(url).then((json) => setData(json)).then(e => setErr(e))
```

Is a reason to create services or they are redundant in my case being enough to fetch data only using `httpService` without creating many services in my app?

Comment: It's about separation of concerns. You could inline fetches everywhere if you wanted to, but services (if implemented sensibly) mean looser coupling and more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is strange, and doesn't make a ton of sense to me.

It doesn't look like your `getPostService` returns any service, it literally just wraps the `httpService.get` function, with no real benefit.

You can see this even clearer when cleaning up the function from:

```js
const getPostService = (url) => {  // this is the service
  return httpService.get(url).then((json) => json)
}
```

To:

```js
const getPostService = url => httpService.get(url);
```

However, if this function was called `getPosts` or it returned a useful object that does operations related to posts, it makes a lot of sense.

For example, maybe your `PostService` kinda looks like this:

```
class PostService {
  getPosts() {} 
  updatePost() {}
  deletePost() { }
}
```

Now your service has some methods that have useful behavior and that can be re-used. If multiple of your components need a 'list of posts', and if all those components just do HTTP requests, then you need to change *all* components if you want to change something about how 'lists of posts' are fetched.

Putting this in a central place increases maintainability

Comment: Could you please add in your answer how to use the service? It will be very helpful

Comment: Honestly, no. I feel I answered the question and this is not a code writing / mentoring service. Do some of your own research and if you get blocked somewhere, ask another (more specific) question.

Comment: @Asking ...call its methods?

Comment: Yes, this isn’t a code mentoring

Comment: @Asking I have a Node.js service that uses a services concept, if you just want to browse around a repo. https://github.com/badgateway/tt-api/blob/main/src/project/service.ts